# children[i] is undefined while removing object from the scene

Tags: javascript, three.js, typeerror, traversal

I want to remove an object from the scene:

```js
removeLegoByPos = (pos) => {
    this.scene.traverse((child) => {
        if (child.isGroup && child.userData.position) {
            if (child.userData.position.equals(pos)) {
                console.log(child.name);
                this.scene.remove(child);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But I get an error:

```bash
lego_113

Uncaught TypeError: children[i] is undefined
    traverse three.module.js:7944
```

Can you please tell me how can I solve this issue? thanks in advance.

Comment: Could it be because you're deleting the child while traversing the scene?

Comment: Yeah, the suggestion above is correct. Don’t add or remove children from the scene while traversing the scene. That’ll throw off the loop because it’ll start with a different count than when it ends. Instead, save a reference of the object you want to remove, let the loop finish, then remove the object afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Possible Error**
a THREE.Group can have THREE.Mesh/Three.Object3D as its children so when you traverse and reach this group and remove it you remove its children, hence when the traverser goes to the next index it should be its child which was already removed.
[image]
**below solution might fix it**

```
const removeLegoByPos = (pos) => {
    let LegoToBeRemoved = undefined

    this.scene.traverse((child) => {
        if (child.isGroup && child.userData.position) {
            if (child.userData.position.equals(pos)) {
                LegoToBeRemoved = child
                // since you found you group google if you can break the traverse, because I'm not sure if you can
            }
        }
    })

    if (legoToBeRemoved) {
        legoToBeRemoved.removeFromParent()
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```